# Rotate image and after crop it with Jcrop.js plugin for phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, rotation, jcrop

Im working in a app that I need to manipulate images. First I need to rotate the image that I get from the camera or gallery. Secondly I need to call to Jcrop.js from this rotated image.

Any ideas, please?

Regards

Comment: with Jcrop you can't rotate as far as I remember. You would have to rotate image and save it than load into Jcrop and crop it and save it again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer...and how can do it? Can you show me the way? some code, please? Im a novice with this!

Comment: I haven't done it in phonegap, but if you want to use jcrop i can imagine it will be similar. jcrop gives you only crop information not the actual cropped image, you have to crop it in backend, whatever that might be. It depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. You might be better off with some different rotate/crop plugin based on html5 canvas.